# Is there any way to get rid off IBM BPM warnings for intermediate events being correlated on invalid output parameter?

Tags: ibm-bpm

I'm an IBM BPM developer and I have following issue:
On my BPD I have an intermediate event that is triggered by a UCA that is called from an Human Service. Everything is working fine, the only problem is that I always get a warning like this in the System.Out.log:

*CWLLG0297W: The intermediate event with ID BpdEvent.51155527-fdce-45de-b2be-5da9fb67ab7a can never receive a message from UCA UCA.5e12e401-0968-49f4-8c63-fb7110fdbfb6 because it is correlated on an invalid output parameter.*

I tried correlation on *tw.system.process.instanceId* and *tw.system.currentProcessInstance.id*, both works, but both rise the warning. Following my researches that's a common issue for BPM 7.5 and 8, but I'm using 8.5.6 and also in 8.5.5 the behaviour is the same.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When was the last time the BPM server was restarted? is it a Process Server or Process Center? Do you have older active instances? Do you have any service attached or you use a simple/complex variable? Did the definition of your UCA (input or output) has changed from the time it was created?

Comment: The server is restarted around every second week, and it's a Process Center. I created a new Process App just for testing this behaviour, thus I had nor older instances neither changes in my UCA definition. And I tried with both, service and variables.

Answer (score 0):

> No, IME stands for "Intermediate Message Event", which is the widget on the BPD that listens for the UCA completion that it will use to correlate.  A UCA can't really have a correlation problem, since it does do correlation.  A correlation problem is a problem with the listener, a.k.a. the IME.  All I'm suggesting is that you pick one of the listeners on the BPD, delete it and recreate it.  The test to see if it is now correlating properly.  If so, then you fell victim to a copy/paste bug.

from https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=1fd6422f-c361-413f-a5f9-7280557e269d

Comment: Doesn't help. As described the correlation works and as I tested with a Process App that was created from scratch, there can be no copy/paste cause. The question was about the warnings in the System.Out.log.